# What does the different furniture do?

Tags: unholy-heights

The description for the desk says *"monsters with desks learn how to resist magic."*

Presumably the other furniture affects their stats/happiness somehow, but the descriptions don't explain how.  **What does the furniture affect?**

Answer (score 1):

I've come here looking for similar answers.  Once thing I can add -- the monsters only seem to regenerate health when they are eating and sleeping in the apartment.  (Other activities don't seem to affect their health/energy bar, except for "making love", which reduces it).

I'm assuming, therefore, that a better fridge and bed might help them regenerate health faster.

Other items seem to affect how long they stay at home -- whether they need to go out for entertainment or they can stay home and fulfill that need.

I would love if the developer, etc. could post some meaningful stats on the various objects.